# How to uncompress files "user" in c drive

Tags: compression, user, undo

So I did this thing without knowing the consequences.

I went to the

local c drive > User folder > left click the file > attributes > Click advanced > clicked "compress content to save disk space" > clicked ok > apply> ok

But here is the problem I did this without knowing what would happen, now half of my folders, content, and app on my computer are gone. The user file of the c drive disappeared. Now I don't know what to do or how to get back all the files because those were important.

Please can you help me out in this situation, what to do, and how to get back all those files in the previous state?

Other information is

> the user file was 48gbs last time
> I am using an Asus tuf laptop with windows 11 ( i7 4000 series, 16 GB Ram , 3050 graphics)

Comment: I think its more likely you selected Delete.  Look at all the filesystem including hidden and system folders/drives.  Otherwise

Comment: Compressing files does **not** delete them. However, during the time the files are being rewritten to compress them, they may not be available. It could be you've not been patient while this process proceeds. in any event, if something *did* go wrong, just recover the disk from your last disk image.